# ActiveRecord has_many and belongs_to on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've looked into this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446757/has-many-and-belongs-to-within-same-model) but I still have trouble wrapping my head around the concept.

I have a similar setup with the linked SO question, in that I have a `User` class that contains both Employees and Managers. I also have another model for `Role` (holding the role names) and `UserRole` (holding which user has which role).

My requirements state that an Employee (a `User` whose `Role` is `User`) can only have one Manager (a `User` whose `Role` is `Manager`). Now, this Managering concept is an addition to the current system, and I'm not supposed to change the `users` table, so I'm making a new table with their own MVC.

But now I find it hard to use `has_many` and `belongs_to` like the linked question. How do I use the new model? I tried using `:through` but it doesn't work (for some reason).

Am I doing it wrong? Should I just add a `manager_id` column to `users` and work the solution in the linked question into my problem? Also, how do I ensure that only a `User` whose `Role` is `Manager` can be set as a Manager?

**Note:** I have to say that I'm relatively new to Rails and ActiveRecord, and even Ruby in general.

**Note 2:** I'm using Rails 4.2.0 if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a many to many system with roles is pretty straight forward:

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.where(name: role).any?
  end
end

class Role
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :role, :user
end
```

Just make sure you create a unique index on UserRole for role and user:

```
add_index :user_roles, [:role_id, :user_id], unique: true
```

The simplest and performant way to implement the manager requirement would be to add a
`mananger_id` column to `users` and setup a self-referencing one to many relationship:

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :subordinates, foreign_key: :manager_id, class_name: 'User'

  validate :authorize_manager!

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.where(name: role).any?
  end

  private
  def authorize_manager!
    if manager.present?
    errors.add(:manager, "does not have manager role") unless manager.has_role?("manager") 
    end
  end
end
```

Another way to do this would be to use resource scoped roles.
The best part is that you don't have build it yourself. There is a excellent gem created by the community called [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) which sets you up with such as system.

Its also quite a bit more flexible than the former system, once you get a hang of it you can add roles to any kind of resource in your domain.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  resourcify
end

---

the_boss = User.find(1)
bob = User.find_by(name: 'Bob')

# creating roles
the_boss.add_role(:manager) # add a global role
the_boss.add_role(:manager, bob) # add a role scoped to a user instance

# querying roles
bob.has_role?(:manager) # => false 
the_boss.has_role?(:manager) # => true
the_boss.has_role?(:manager, bob) # => true
the_boss.has_role?(:manager, User.create) # => false
```

If you go with Rolify compliment it with an authorization library such as Pundit or CanCanCan to enforce the rules.

Comment: I'm not supposed to edit the `users` table, but if the other option is adding yet another gem, maybe a new column isn't such a bad idea.

Comment: I think I'm going with the `manager_id` column. How do I get the newly inserted manager's name for the error message? EDIT: Nevermind, I figured out `manager.name`.

Comment: "adding yet another gem" is not always a bad thing. Don't reinvent the wheel because of fear of technical dept or not invented here syndrome.

Comment: This especially applies to authentication and authorization. Thats why people get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :employees, foreign_key: :manager_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Does it helps ?

**Update:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role, through: :user_role
  belongs_to :manager, -> { where(role: {name: 'manager'}), class_name: 'User'
  has_many :employees, -> { where(role: {name: 'employee'}), foreign_key: :manager_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Comment: That's the linked question's solution, but I can't make it work. How do I bring the new table into the association?

Comment: What about this update ? Not sure that's what you're trying to accomplish but you maybe should take a look on that kind of structure.

Comment: Hm, so I should/must add a `manager_id` column to the `users` table?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do but if you want to link a user to another one which will be his parent with the same class, using a foreign_key like this is a good way to do that.